# Set destination to an existing sapui5 html5 application

Tags: sapui5, hana

I have a html5 application, called Portal that holds a collection of tiles that simply link to other apps when pressed. I created a custom domain for the portal app. So now when I call https://example.org it shows the portal app.

What I want to do is to show other apps by calling https://example.org/{app_name}. For example http://example.org/records should show the records app. I tried to accomplish this using Destinations, but without any luck. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: btw. destinations are used to connect to data sources or pass authentication credentials, but not for navigation, this is normally done by a router.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SAP Cloud Platform Portal or onPrem NW GW Fiori Launchpad you could use app-to-app-navigation with semantic objects:

Cloud: https://help.sap.com/viewer/3ca6847da92847d79b27753d690ac5d5/Cloud/en-US/1a51a606964141579d14079455ac03b8.html

OnPrem: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/23/cross-app-navigation-in-sap-fiori-launchpad/

OnPrem with Web IDE: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/02/19/app-to-app-navigation-in-the-web-ide-fiori-launchpad-sandbox/

If you have a custom Portal, it depends where your apps are deployed. You might need a dns entry solving https://example.org/{app_name} to the real url where the app is available.